# Can I get a warning when editing code in site-packages?

Tags: pydev

When debugging with pydev, I frequently end up with an editor window for files in my site-packages directory. This can result in lost work, after doing `python setup.py install` thinking I made the change in my working directory.

Is it possible to have pydev warn me when editing files in site-packages?